# using jquery numscroller in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Trying to use [numscroller](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Counting-Up-Numbers-While-Scrolling-numscroller/) dynamically and it doesn't work.

**static usage (work):**

```
<span class='numscroller' data-min='1' data-max='1000' data-delay='5' data-increment='10'>1000</span>
```

**dynamic usage (doesn't work):**

```
    $("#product-total-view").addClass('numscroller');
    $("#product-total-view").text(10000);
    $("#product-total-view").attr('data-delay',5);
    $("#product-total-view").attr('data-increment',10);
    $("#product-total-view").attr('data-min',1);
    $("#product-total-view").attr('data-max',10000);
```

any idea if it possible and how?

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? What errors are you getting? What is/isn't it doing that it shouldn't/should be doing?

Comment: it doesn't scroll the numbers, I see just the final number

Comment: Add  `$(".numscroller").numscroller()` at the end of that list.

Comment: I'll try and update

Comment: Won't work because that plugin is really crappy low quality code.

Comment: `$(...).numscroller is not a function` and I do load the `numscroller-1.0.js` file..

Comment: @connexo alternatives?

Comment: @connexo: Because you can't run it doesn't make a plugin crappy.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette It does, because it takes away control from you.

Comment: Btw, `$("#product-total-view").addClass('numscroller').text(10000).data({ delay: 5, increment: 10, min: 1, max: 10000});` is a little more concise and alot faster.

Comment: @connexo: Good advise to chain... But the issue is to add the class LAST. And... As I can now see... To use the right selector. .oO(lol)

Answer (score 1):

Add the `numscroller` class AFTER the attributes are setted.

It works fine.
;)

```js
// No CDN for "numscroller"... So look around line #94 (at the bottom) for OP code.

/**
* jQuery scroroller Plugin 1.0
*
* http://www.tinywall.net/
* 
* Developers: Arun David, Boobalan
* Copyright (c) 2014 
*/
(function($){
  $(window).on("load",function(){
    $(document).scrollzipInit();
    $(document).rollerInit();
  });
  $(window).on("load scroll resize", function(){
    $('.numscroller').scrollzip({
      showFunction    :   function() {
        numberRoller($(this).attr('data-slno'));
      },
      wholeVisible    :     false,
    });
  });
  $.fn.scrollzipInit=function(){
    $('body').prepend("<div style='position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:0;height:0;' id='scrollzipPoint'></div>" );
  };
  $.fn.rollerInit=function(){
    var i=0;
    $('.numscroller').each(function() {
      i++;
      $(this).attr('data-slno',i); 
      $(this).addClass("roller-title-number-"+i);
    });        
  };
  $.fn.scrollzip = function(options){
    var settings = $.extend({
      showFunction    : null,
      hideFunction    : null,
      showShift       : 0,
      wholeVisible    : false,
      hideShift       : 0,
    }, options);
    return this.each(function(i,obj){
      $(this).addClass('scrollzip');
      if ( $.isFunction( settings.showFunction ) ){
        if(
          !$(this).hasClass('isShown')&&
          ($(window).outerHeight()+$('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top-settings.showShift)>($(this).offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))&&
          ($('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))<($(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top-settings.showShift)
        ){
          $(this).addClass('isShown');
          settings.showFunction.call( this );
        }
      }
      if ( $.isFunction( settings.hideFunction ) ){
        if(
          $(this).hasClass('isShown')&&
          (($(window).outerHeight()+$('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top-settings.hideShift)<($(this).offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))||
           ($('#scrollzipPoint').offset().top+((settings.wholeVisible)?$(this).outerHeight():0))>($(this).outerHeight()+$(this).offset().top-settings.hideShift))
        ){
          $(this).removeClass('isShown');
          settings.hideFunction.call( this );
        }
      }
      return this;
    });
  };
  function numberRoller(slno){
    var min=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-min');
    var max=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-max');
    var timediff=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-delay');
    var increment=$('.roller-title-number-'+slno).attr('data-increment');
    var numdiff=max-min;
    var timeout=(timediff*1000)/numdiff;
    //if(numinc<10){
    //increment=Math.floor((timediff*1000)/10);
    //}//alert(increment);
    numberRoll(slno,min,max,increment,timeout);

  }
  function numberRoll(slno,min,max,increment,timeout){//alert(slno+"="+min+"="+max+"="+increment+"="+timeout);
    if(min<=max){
      $('.roller-title-number-'+slno).html(min);
      min=parseInt(min)+parseInt(increment);
      setTimeout(function(){numberRoll(eval(slno),eval(min),eval(max),eval(increment),eval(timeout))},timeout);
    }else{
      $('.roller-title-number-'+slno).html(max);
    }
  }
})(jQuery);



$("#product-total-view").text(10000);
$("#product-total-view").attr('data-delay',5);
$("#product-total-view").attr('data-increment',10);
$("#product-total-view").attr('data-min',1);
$("#product-total-view").attr('data-max',10000);

// Add the class last!!!
$("#product-total-view").addClass('numscroller');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="product-total-view"></span>
```

Comment: look good, but still doesn't work for me. I tried to add in to the following dashboard: https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella which run a lot of external libs too. maybe one of them override it.. I'll try to solve it and update soon

Comment: Have a look at if `#product-total-view` also is dynamically generated. In that case, use `$(document).find("#product-total-view)`... ;) I can't see where that could overlap... But the inexistance of the element when the script runs is a big possibility. ;)

Comment: A good test (I didn't analyse your project at all) would be this right before setting the attributes: `if($("#product-total-view").length>0){console.log("Element is there!")}else{console.log("Hey! I need an element to work!")}` ;)

Comment: Element is there! but I still see the final number with no animation

Comment: When I input EXACTLY the console test suggested above in the console of [your Github](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html)... I get the `Hey! I need an element to work!` So then... Look for typos. ;)

Comment: read my prev comment (it's not my code, I cloned it and change things locally). I just wonder if you see some other lib that can brake this one.

Comment: Yeah... That is a div class count. not #product-total-view.

Comment: The full selector for that 2500 "Total users" (as rendered) would be `body > div.container.body > div > div.right_col > div.row.tile_count > div:nth-child(1) > div.count`

Comment: Try with `$(document).find(".tile_count div.count").first()` instead of `$("#product-total-view")` That's the right one. ;)